# How to add variable to PATH system variable?

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

I am trying to add to my Windows 10 a new folder to my existing PATH system variable.
But I'd like to add it as a nested variable. 
So what I did was:

1. Create a variable for my folder as a system varaible: 
   `bla=c:\dev`
2. Added the folder I created as a param to my existing path: 
   `PATH={current path};%bla%`

But, after restarting,  when trying to use it the path didn't recognize the new variable. When I tried to view the PATH from command line I saw the varaible unrecognized. meaning when I typed: c:>set path

I got: {path};%bla%

What should I do in order to use variable as part of my path. Should it be located in another place and not a a **system varaible**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to run executables located in the folder "C:\dev" (if this is what you are trying to achieve if I unterstood right), you have to:

1. Select the "Path" item in the list of system variables;
2. Click "Edit..." below;
3. Click "New" in the opened form;
4. Type "C:\dev" (your folder);
5. Confirm and closing the form clicking on "OK";

**EDIT:**

My bad, totally useless answer. I did not read the question carefully.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.